# Displaying all sysvinit init scripts

Tags: debian, init-script, sysvinit

Is there some tool that displays all available init scripts (on Debian), short of one having to remember a location like `/etc/init.d`, not to mention that not everything in there is an init script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `chkconfig` utility can do this. Unlike `RHEL` or `SLES`, it does not come installed by default in `Debian`, but it is a good end-user tool for sysvinit configuration. To list all sysvinit services:

```
chkconfig --list
```